# Spring Social /connect/twitter Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-social

I'm following http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/ to setup spring social for twitter with Spring boot but when I run the application and redirected to localhost:8080/connect/twitter I'm getting:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
>   Request method 'GET' not supported

I know this have something to do with with the mapping of ConnectController how do I really fix this?

```
@Controller
public class HelloTwitterController {
    private final Twitter twitter;
    private final ConnectionRepository connectionRepo;

    @Inject
    public MessoTwitterController(Twitter twitter, ConnectionRepository connectionRepo) {
        this.twitter = twitter;
        this.connectionRepo = connectionRepo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeTwitter (Model model) {
        if (connectionRepo.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class) == null)
            return "redirect:/connect/twitter";

        model.addAttribute(twitter.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        model.addAttribute("friends", twitter.friendOperations().getFriends());
        return "welcomeTwitter";
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.mypackage")
public class MyApplication {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your Controller class

Comment: I just added the Controller

Comment: what is the URL you are hitting and is there no path mapping on top of your controller?

Comment: I'm hitting localhost:8080 and there is no path mapping on top of the controller

Comment: I found the problem I did not setup my view resolver so Connect/twitterConnect is not being found

Comment: Can you post it as a solution...;-) Slap the code in there?

Comment: Yes, please provide your solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no view resolver in your code so the views (returned strings) cannot be rendered.

You have to add your view resolver (e.g. thymeleaf, freemarker, jsp) or put this line in application.properties

```
spring.social.auto_connection_views=true
```

This will render your views using default templates.

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitry Zlykh is right about the missing view resolver, but you don't need to enable it explicitly. Having an appropriate dependency in your build file is good enough, Boot will automatically enable the view resolver. If using Thymeleaf, the code that does that is [ThymeleafAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java).

For a Gradle project, put the following in the `build.gradle`, and you should be all set.

```
runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
```